# Stirring in bomb calorimeter

Tags: thermodynamics

So I recently learned about bomb calorimeter and it said that we stirred it to have temperature constant all over, but we also need it to be accurate so doesn't stirring also generate heat, so do they account for it or just neglect it.

Comment: Stirring can add energy to the system via work, but this is likely an incredibly small amount of energy relative to the amount of energy added/removed via heating, so it can be ignored.  However, you would need to take into account the energy added to or removed from the *stirrer*.  All of that said, I don't know the details of how bomb calorimeters work, so there are probably practical considerations that this comment ignores (hence a comment and not an answer).

Comment: Yeah, I knew that the stirrer would also take some energy, was only confused about the stirring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Randall Munroe [estimates](https://what-if.xkcd.com/71/) (on the basis of Brawn Mixer, [Principles of Fluid Mixing](https://fliphtml5.com/bcza/bgdc/basic)) that vigorous stirring adds heat at the rate of one ten-millionth of a watt.

If you had 1 gram of water in the bomb calorimeter, it would take 4.184 J to raise its temperature by 1 degree C, or over a year at this rate. Stirring for an hour would raise the temperature by about 0.000001 degrees.

Adjust heat capacity, mass, and stirring power and time as needed, but unless you have a highly sensitive device I doubt you'll be able to notice.